# Resize of image as array of bytes

Tags: c#, file-upload, arrays, image-resizing

I am currently trying to resize an image to a thumbnail, to show as a preview when its done uploading. I am using fineuploader plugin for the uploading part of the image. I consistently keep getting a "parameter is not valid". I've seen many posts related to this, and tried most of the solution, but have no success. Here is the snippet of the code:

```
    public static byte[] CreateThumbnail(byte[] PassedImage, int LargestSide)  
    {  
        byte[] ReturnedThumbnail = null;  

        using (MemoryStream StartMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(),  
                            NewMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())  
        {  
            StartMemoryStream.Write(PassedImage, 0, PassedImage.Length); //error being fire in this line 

            System.Drawing.Bitmap startBitmap = new Bitmap(StartMemoryStream);  

            int newHeight;  
            int newWidth;  
            double HW_ratio;  
            if (startBitmap.Height > startBitmap.Width)  
            {  
                newHeight = LargestSide;  
                HW_ratio = (double)((double)LargestSide / (double)startBitmap.Height);  
                newWidth = (int)(HW_ratio * (double)startBitmap.Width);  
            }  
            else 
            {  
                newWidth = LargestSide;  
                HW_ratio = (double)((double)LargestSide / (double)startBitmap.Width);  
                newHeight = (int)(HW_ratio * (double)startBitmap.Height);  
            }  

            System.Drawing.Bitmap newBitmap = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);  

            newBitmap = ResizeImage(startBitmap, newWidth, newHeight);  

            newBitmap.Save(NewMemoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);  

            ReturnedThumbnail = NewMemoryStream.ToArray(); 
        }  

        return ReturnedThumbnail;  
    }
```

I'm out of ideas, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in the `new Bitmap(startMemoryStream)` line, not the line above.

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7ha67kw.aspx) states that this exception can occur when:

> stream does not contain image data or is null.
>
> -or-
>
> stream contains a PNG image file with a single dimension greater than 65,535 pixels.

You should check that you have a valid PNG file in there. For example, write it to a file and try opening it in an image viewer.

Comment: I'll try to write it to a file, didn't knew it had to be a png file, thanks for the pointing out.

Comment: the image is valid, as the original one is store successfully in the sharepoint list. The array of bytes isn't null either as I successfully print out its length. Any ideas?

Comment: I tested part of your method by loading my own PNG from file to bytes and feeding that, and it worked. Your code in this method is correct up to and including the constructor. So maybe there is a problem with the code that reads the image from the sharepoint list? Again, use a `BinaryWriter` and `File.Create` to write your bytes to file and see if it is correct.

Comment: Ill try that right away. Btw I dont read the image from the sharepoint list, I get the bytes from the uploader sent from the webpage. I am currently using fineuploader plugin for this job.

Comment: I wrote to disk the bytes from the image, everything seems fine.

Answer (score -1):

That code is dangerous - every instance of a System.Drawing class **must** be placed in a using(){} clause.

Here's an alternate solution that uses the `ImageResizer` NuGet package and resizes the image safely.

```
var ms = new MemoryStream();
ImageResizer.Current.Build(PassedImage, ms, new ResizeSettings(){MaxWidth=LargestSide, MaxHeight=LargestSide});
return ImageResizer.ExtensionMethods.StreamExtensions.CopyToBytes(ms);
```